# How can I parse a Symfony parameter into the fixtures.yml file of Alice

Tags: php, symfony, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I'm stuck with the package [nelmio/alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) (Expressive fixtures generator). I don't know how to parse a parameter from the general `config/parameters.yml` (in my case 'photoupload_directory') file into the `fixtures.yml`.

Now I have something hard coded like this:

`photo: <Image('/Users/vivi/projects.2016/cvsymfony.local/storage/uploads/photos',1080,800,false,false)>`...

I tried already:

`photo:
<Image(getParameter('photoupload_directory'),1080,800,false,false)>`

but this is not working either. I also tried

`$this->getParameter and $this->getContainer()->getParameter` or the `%photoupload_directory%` notation).

Already searched the internet but so far nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally one solution, probably there are more (for parsing the parameters to this class), so if you know let me know. Below worked for me..

First add the name space ContainerAwareInterface :

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
```

Add the Trait (in the class):

```
use \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
```

Create the function:

```
public function getPhotoUploadDir()
{
    return $this->container->getParameter('photoupload_directory');
}
```

In the fixtures.yml

```
photo: <Image($this->fake('getPhotoUploadDir'),1080,800,false,false)>
```